# Hibernate type used to map java.lang.Double

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, double, hibernate-tools

I am using "double" in Hibernate .hbm.xml files, and when I generate classes with Hibernate Tool I get class property which has primitive type double. I want this property to be java wrapper type Double. How can I achieve this? If I change this manually in my classes, is it going to give any issues to hibernate?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want "double" and not "BigDecimal"? For monetary values, "double" is problematic because of rounding (3.11 - 3.1 is not 0.01 using double).

Answer (score 1):

> I am using "double" in Hibernate .hbm.xml files, and when I generate classes with Hibernate Tool I get class property which has primitive type double. I want this property to be java wrapper type Double. How can I achieve this?

Is the property nullable in the `hbm.xml` mapping? If it is, you should get a `Double`.

If you can't change the mapping, you could override the default behavior:

- override the column specifically in [reveng.xml](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html#hibernaterevengxmlfile)
- use a [`type-mapping`](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html#type_map) and `not-null` set to `false` to handle it for all columns

Answer (score 0):

It only issue you could have is if your property is null amd the column is declared as not null. So I would advise you to always initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add below statement under type-mapping in your hibernate.reveng.xml ,then you pojos will be generated with double type as java.lang.Double.

```
<sql-type jdbc-type="DOUBLE"  not-null="false" hibernate-type="double" />
```

Or

if you can add **not-null="false"** in your hbm files,that also address your issue.

```
<property name="salary" type="double">
            <column name="SALARY"  not-null="false" />
        </property>
```